# socket.io event not working when calling a file with $.get

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I have been learning express with socket and I cant seem to get my code to work the way I want it. Basically I am doing a $.get call that pulls through and replaces the HTML on my index page. This is done after the server has confirmed that the new user is added at it meets the correct requirements.

The $.get works perfectly, it pulls through the other files html. However the socket events then stop working and I cant understand as to why. What it should be doing is adding the persons username next to the chat box and when someone types something it should then reflect that as well.

It would seem that the server isnt liking that I am calling a different file or something along those lines?

Here is a direct link to my GIT: https://github.com/factordog/letsGuess
So that if you need to see how everything is set you can check directly, I am not sure what is required.

This is the code in question:

```
        $.get("./pages/game.html" ,function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $("#test").html(data);
        });
```

And this is the actual client side js:

```
$(function($) {

    // Variables
    var socket          = io.connect(),// Creates the connection variable
        setUsername     = $("#setUsername"), //Form for when a user join
        newUser         = $("#username"), // Input for where user inputs a name
        userSuccess     = $(".successMessage"), // Success container for valid username
        userError       = $(".errorMessage"), // Error container for invalid username
        playerOne       = null, 
        playerTwo       = null;

    // Submit function for when a user submits their desired username
    setUsername.submit(function(e){
        // Prevent sumbit button default
        e.preventDefault();

        // Gets value of the username. function(data) allows us to reference the app.js
        // data which is the array of new users.
        socket.emit("new user", newUser.val(), function(data){
            // Checks if name is valid else displays an error
            if(data) {
                socket.on("full_lobby_check", function(data){
                    console.log(data.lobbyStatus);
                });
                // Fades out the login page
                userSuccess.removeClass("hide");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#loginPage").fadeOut();
                }, 1000);
                // Create a smoother transition between pages

                $.get("./pages/game.html" ,function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#test").html(data);
                });

                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#gamePage').fadeIn();
                }, 2000);
            } else {
                userError.removeClass("hide");
            }
        });

        newUser.val("");
    });

    // ===============================================
    // PLAYER VS PLAYER APPEND
    // ===============================================

    // Append player names to battle
    socket.on("event_new_user", function(data){
        playerOne = data.userOne;
        playerTwo = data.userTwo;
        $(".playerOne").append(playerOne);
        $(".playerTwo").append(playerTwo);
    });


    // ===============================================
    // MESSAGE BOX LOGIC
    // ===============================================
    var users           = $(".playersOnline"), // Area to append all users names
        messageForm     = $(".sendMessage"),
        messageBox      = $(".message"),
        chat            = $(".chat");

    // Display all the usernames in chat room area
    socket.on("usernames", function(data){
        var html ="";
        for(i=0 ; i < data.length; i++) {
            html += data[i] + "<br/>";
        }
        users.html(html);
    });

    // On sumbit sends message to server to be fufilled
    messageForm.click(function(e){
        // Prevent sumbit button default
        e.preventDefault();
        socket.emit("send message", messageBox.val());
        messageBox.val('');
    });

    // Appends the new message from the user to the chat box
    socket.on("new message", function(data){
        console.log(data.user);
        chat.append("<b>" + data.user + ": </b>" + data.msg + "<br/>");
    }); 
})
```

;

EDIT:

Included pastebin of current: http://pastebin.com/WUzwuPrf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue I see is the order in which events in your code are happening. The $.get shouldn't effect the performance of socket.io, but rather the issue is in the fact that you are asynchronously getting the html code, so your page may only get the html file AFTER it has gotten the socket.io events.

Let me step through the passage of what runs in your code:

1.

```
var users           = $(".playersOnline"), // Area to append all  users names
    messageForm     = $(".sendMessage"),
    messageBox      = $(".message"),
    chat            = $(".chat");
```

The above lines run on page load. But, on page load, you haven't loaded the html yet so jquery will not be able to find any of these elements. Note: it won't give an error as jquery will nicely handle all operations involving 0 elements.

2.
After the form is submitted

```
// Display all the usernames in chat room area
socket.on("usernames", function(data){
    var html ="";
    for(i=0 ; i < data.length; i++) {
        html += data[i] + "<br/>";
    }
    users.html(html);
});
```

Most likely this event will be executed right after the form is submitted (but before the html loads). This is because the websocket used by socket.io is pretty fast! Again the same issue arises as `users` is still a jquery selector for 0 elements as the html isn't in the DOM yet.

3.

```
    $.get("./pages/game.html" ,function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $("#test").html(data);
    });
```

Finally after everything else runs, this will most likely fire last. The callback function will set the html on the page and insert all the elements into the DOM. BUT, it is too late because all the other socket.io events have likely already been executed without any elements on the page to place all their data.

**TLDR:** For socket.io events you should make sure that your server doesn't send them until your page is ready (perhaps separate the 'new user' event into a 'new user' and 'page ready' event), or you can store the data globally and only put it on the page when the $.get is finished (this second option is not recommended as it still leaves open a timing issue).

Make sure that if you do something like `var users = $(".playersOnline")`, you only do it in code run after $.get is done updating the page (same goes for things like `users.html(html);`). I'd recommend making a `function gamepage_ready(){...}` function which is called by $.get after the html is inserted which takes care of inserting the data from socket.io into the page.

Comment: I tried putting all my socket code in a function called chatRoom() but when I fired it off after the $.get the socket events still dont work.

Comment: Okay I have created  a pastebin. What I have done now is created a variable called d1. This stores my ajax call which will then load the game.html. Then under my submit function i check when the call is done then i execute my other functions. Only problem that I am having now is if possible I would like for it to only load the game.html on sumbit

Comment: If you need to load game.html after the submit, then you'd need to either store the data from the socket.io events globally to insert into the page after the html loads or change the server to delay sending the events until after it gets an ok from the browser that the html file is loaded.